# What molecule's models might Linus Pauling be holding up in this photo? Perhaps something akin to pentagonal dodecahedrane, or could they be viruses?

Tags: chemistry, pauling

The Chemistry SE question [What dodecahedral molecule is Linus Pauling likely holding in this photograph? Does it have 40 carbon atoms?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/159395/16035) begins:

> The video [Quasicrystals ; Prof. Daniel Shechtman ; Nobel Prize in Chemistry](https://youtu.be/V2GqU6fdjeQ?t=420) focuses on [Professor Dan Shechtman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Shechtman) but happens to include some photos of Linus Pauling **who never believed in [quasicrystals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasicrystal).** From the video:
>
> > The leader of that group was Professor Linus Pauling, a two-time Nobel laureate. He was a very important figure and an idol of the American Chemical Society, **and to his last day, he was standing on stages and published papers saying that "Daniel Shechtman is talking nonsense."**
>
> During this part of the video there is shown a photo of Linus Pauling holding some ball and stick molecular models. These appear to be [dodecahedral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_dodecahedron) arrangements (12 pentagons, 20 vertices) of possibly carbon atoms.

From each atom of the dodecahedron another atom protrudes.

The question was closed as "opinion-based" because it was decided that a fact-based answer to what Pauling was holding up in the 1950's photograph couldn't be identified with sufficient certainty for a Chemistry SE answer.

[There was speculation there](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/159395/what-dodecahedral-molecule-is-linus-pauling-likely-holding-in-this-photograph-d#comment327700_159395) that this was in 1954 "taken on occasion of (Pauling's) 1954 NP (Nobel Prize) award".

As it is now too late to migrate but I can't get this image nor this structure out of my craw as evidenced by two new Chemistry SE questions:

- [Has substitution of all 20 hydrogen atoms of pentagonal dodecahedrane ever succeeded? If not, is there any reason that it can not be done?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/163833/16035)
- [Has a fully methylated pentagonal dodecahedrane been synthesized or at least attempted? If not, is there some reason it could not exist?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/163832/16035)

I'd like to now ask:

**Question:** What molecule's models might Linus Pauling be holding up in this photo? Perhaps something akin to pentagonal dodecahedrane, or could they be viruses?*

Clearly I'm grasping at straws, but there might be a recording or transcript of some speech related to Pauling's 1954 Nobel Prize award.

[image: screenshot from the video "Quasicrystals ; Prof. Daniel Shechtman ; Nobel Prize in Chemistry" https://youtu.be/V2GqU6fdjeQ?t=420]

Comment: The [first image of a Human coronavirus was published in 1967](https://microbiologysociety.org/blog/in-pictures-the-first-images-of-a-coronavirus.html) but [TEM microscopy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_electron_microscopy) started a lot earlier than that. To that end I've just asked [When was the first electron microscope image of a roundish or geometrical spiked virus particle produced?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/14298/3869)

Comment: This is a photograph taken by Tom Hollyman in 1956. https://www.bhollymangallery.com/gallery.html?gallery=Thomas%20Benton%20Hollyman%20-%20%20%22Some%20Creatives%22%20Show&sortNumber=44&skipno=0&loadedNumber=0